# jQuery selection of a button created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a button on the fly and appending it to a div.
I want to capture the click event on that button.

```
function(){
  $('#menuDiv').append('<div class ="buttonWrapper"><input type="button" id="addToOrder" name="addToOrder" value="Add to order"></div>');
}
```

and then trying to capture the click event with this

```
$("#addToOrder").click(function () {
  //Grab the selections made on the form
  window.alert('i m in add to order');
  updateOrderWindow();
});
```

This function is not executing. Don't know why. I have also tried it with the `.buttonWrapper` div class but it didn't work.

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: Use Event delegation such as 'on' events to bind dynamic elements

Comment: With literal your title as search words you have your answer at the first link appearing.

Comment: @KilianStinson It did not show, otherwise why bother writing the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler to bind dynamically created elements:

```
$('#menuDiv').on('click', '#addToOrder', function () {
    //Grab the selections made on the form
    window.alert('i m in add to order');
    updateOrderWindow();
});
```

This will bind the event itself to the `menuDiv` element, and will run the `click` handler for any children `#addToOrder`

Answer (score 0):

Problem that your `button created dynamically`

You can try to use next code

```
$(document).on("click", "#addToOrder", function(){
  alert ('button clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```js
$(function(){
  $('#menuDiv').append('<div class ="buttonWrapper"><input type="button" id="addToOrder" name="addToOrder" value="Add to order"></div>');
});
$('#menuDiv').on('click','#addToOrder', function (){
  //Grab the selections made on the form
  window.alert('i m in add to order');
  //updateOrderWindow();
});
```

```html
<div id="menuDiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```